# How to catch all edge cases for an optional swift string?

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

The app store is rejecting my app, and I've traced the logs back to the following code. I cannot reproduce the issue and from what I see my code works. But perhaps improving the way the function is written will account for an edge case I missed?

```
func getNSDate(stringDate: String) -> NSDate {
    self.formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"

    guard (self.formatter.dateFromString(stringDate) != nil) else {
        return NSDate()
    }

    return self.formatter.dateFromString(stringDate)!
}    

/*
 * 2016-09-05T19:00:00+0900 -> 午後7:00
 */
func getJapaneseTime(jDateString: String?) -> String {
    let jDate = getNSDate(jDateString!)
    let jTimeOfDay = ["AM":"午前", "PM":"午後"]

    self.formatter.dateFormat = "a"

    let timeOfDay = jTimeOfDay[self.formatter.stringFromDate(jDate)]

    self.formatter.dateFormat = String(format: "%@h:mm", timeOfDay!)
    return self.formatter.stringFromDate(jDate)
}
```

specifically line:

```
self.formatter.dateFormat = String(format: "%@h:mm", timeOfDay!)
```

An example of jDateString: `2016-10-23T19-30-00+09:00`

My crash log states:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000010008af28
Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  0
```

Comment: The first thing to check would be that timeOfDay != nil

Comment: Don't force unwrap optionals using the bang operator (!) .....instead use an if let statement or a guard statement. If you use ! and the variable is nil, your program will crash. That's probably why your app keeps getting rejected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## A:

```
func getJapaneseTime(jDateString: String?) -> String {
    let jDate = getNSDate(jDateString!)
```

`jDateString` in function is assumed to be non-optional, 'cos in only use of it it's force unwrapped, why is it then `optional` in parameters?

It should be

```
func getJapaneseTime(jDateString: String) -> String {
    let jDate = getNSDate(jDateString)
```

Do unwrapping with `guard let` or `if let` outside of it.

## B:

```
let timeOfDay = jTimeOfDay[self.formatter.stringFromDate(jDate)]
self.formatter.dateFormat = String(format: "%@h:mm", timeOfDay!)
```

It should be `if let timeOfDay =` or `guard let timeOfDay =` or use `??` to assign default value if `timeOfDay` is nil.

#### Summary

> DO NOT USE `!` OPERATOR EVERYWHERE. Prefer using `if let`, `guard let` and `??` to safely unwrap optionals.

EDIT: Also, I think that all your code above can be implemented using proper [Locale](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nslocale) and date format with `DateFormatter`.